# Subsetting rows with the help of UDF

Tags: r

A newbie question. I want to subset a dataframe with the help of a UDF.

The UDF is to determine whether a certain value exists in a string which is actually a comma separated list of values.

I've created two versions of the UDF, both returning TRUE/FALSE:

```
blValInListExist1 <- function(inLst,inVal)
 {
  #func is not perfect but it does what I need
  //from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72576226/check-if-comma-delimited-column-contains-a-value
 
  #surround the val with regex boundaries
  sValInBoundaries <- paste0("\\b",inVal,"\\b");

  blRet <- grepl(sValInBoundaries,inLst)
 
  return(blRet)
 }
```

```
blValInListExist2 <- function(inLst,inVal,inDel=",")
 {
  #func works fine on testing but doesn't work in subsetting
  blRet <- inVal %in% unlist(strsplit(inLst, split=inDel))
 
  return(blRet)
 }
```

Now, I've created the base dataframe:

```
iID <- c(1,2,3,4)
tCsv <- c("21,5","1,3","2","a,1")
fVal <- c(1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4)

dfBase <- data.frame(iID,tCsv,fVal)
dfBase
```

```
########
iID tCsv fVal
 1 21,5  1.1
 2  1,3  2.2
 3    2  3.3
 4  a,1  4.4
########
```

I need to make a subset dataframe which takes rows where the variable tCsv contains "1", i.e. the result dataframe should have rows 2 and 4.

So I run this code:

```
df1 <- dfBase[blValInListExist1(dfBase$tCsv,1),]
df1
```

and it generates what I need:

```
########
iID tCsv fVal
 2  1,3  2.2
 4  a,1  4.4
########
```

However if I use the second function it does not work, it takes all rows:

```
df2 <- dfBase[blValInListExist2(dfBase$tCsv,1),]
df2
```

```
########
iID tCsv fVal
 1 21,5  1.1
 2  1,3  2.2
 3    2  3.3
 4  a,1  4.4
########
```

Interesting, that when I test the second function this way:

```
sCsv = "21,5"
blVal <- blValInListExist2(sCsv,1)
blVal
(FALSE)

sCsv = "a,1"
blVal <- blValInListExist2(sCsv,1)
blVal
(TRUE)
```

it works as expected.

So my question is why the second function does not work in subsetting the rows? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 0):

`grepl` returns a boolean (`TRUE`/`FALSE`) vector of the same length of the input vector. This is in contrast to `%in%`, which returns a single boolean value in this specific application - the `%in%` approach here returns all of the values in the data frame because of [vector recycling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15358006/what-is-the-difference-between-in-and).

You can understand this better if you break it down. First, just take your vector of interest, `dfBase$tCsv`:

```
dfBase$tCsv
# [1] "21,5" "1,3"  "2"    "a,1"
```

If you run `grepl`:

```
grepl("1", dfBase$tCsv)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

You get a vector of the same length telling us if the pattern is in each element of the vector.

If you run `%in%`:

```
"1" %in% unlist(strsplit(inLst, split = ","))
# [1] TRUE
```

You get a single value returned telling us if the pattern was anywhere in the vector. In human language it's asking "is the value "1" anywhere in this vector of strings?" to which the answer is simply, "yes".

This gets us to vector recycling. In applying the second function, you are essentially running `dfBase[TRUE,]`. Since a single `TRUE` is shorter than the number of rows, it "recycles" the value TRUE to equal the length of rows.

A better example of how vector recycling plays a role here is if we look at:

```
dfBase[c(TRUE, FALSE),]
```

This will return every other row, because it is recycling TRUE and FALSE:

```
#   iID tCsv fVal
# 1   1 21,5  1.1
# 3   3    2  3.3
```

If you switch the order of the inputs for `%in%` in the second function, it will check every value in the vector against the pattern:

```
unlist(strsplit(dfBase$tCsv, split = inDel)) %in% "1"

# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

If you want a function that will work as you want, you shouldn't check the unlisted values of `strsplit` because that returns a vector longer than the number of rows. Since `strsplit` returns a list, you could use `lapply` to check if `any` element in the list contains the pattern, then unlist those results:

```
blValInListExist3 <- function(inLst, inVal, inDel = ",") {
  ll <- lapply(strsplit(inLst, split = inDel), \(x) any(x %in% inVal))
  return(unlist(ll))
}

dfBase[blValInListExist3(dfBase$tCsv, 1),]

#   iID tCsv fVal
# 2   2  1,3  2.2
# 4   4  a,1  4.4
```

Comment: Hi ipsmith, thank you for your input. Could you tell me in what way I should use the function with %in% to get the rows I need? What is the right syntax?
Thanks!

Comment: @cadol_askUbu see the edit on how you can use `%in%`. good luck!

Comment: Hi @ipsmith,

Well, I've created the third version of the UDF:


`blValInListExist3 <- function(inLst,inVal,inDel=",")`
 {
  `#func doesn't work`
  `blRet <- unlist(strsplit(inLst, split=inDel)) %in% inVal`
 
  `return(blRet)`
 `}`


When I run it


`df3 <- dfBase[blValInListExist3(dfBase$tCsv,1),]
df3`


the result is this



`########
iID tCsv fVal
 3    2  3.3
NA <NA>   NA
########`



Any idea what's wrong now?

Thanks!

Comment: I am struggling to format my answer but no luck

Sorry! (((

Comment: Consider how many elements  `unlist(strsplit(inLst, split = inDel))` returns and how many rows you have in your data frame. See edit for the solution, but you'll learn R best if you critically think about what each line of code is doing and trying to solve for yourself. Good luck!

Comment: It gives me an error on the backslash symbol (at "\(x)"). Is this the right syntax?

Comment: You may have an older version of R. You can replace it with `function(x)`

Comment: it works now, thank a lot!